# Android DDMS Threads

Tags: android, ddms

DDMS threads option is sometimes showing which methods in my code are being run by the thread which is very useful.

But Most of the times it is showing till Looper.loop() for handler threads and nothing later

How to view list of methods that are executed one after other by the thread.

Any other similar or better tools for debugging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use method tracing for this purposes. [Here](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/debugging-tracing.html) you can read how to use it. AFAIR, there is a button in ddms that allows you to start method profiling and after stopping it opens perspective where you can see the results. Moreover, you can put [startMethodTracing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#startMethodTracing%28%29) before and [stopMethodTracing()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Debug.html#stopMethodTracing%28%29) after a method that you want to trace.

Also [this](http://developer.android.com/tools/debugging/ddms.html) link will be useful for you.